# C multiple including

Tags: c, include

I'm trying to understand when I should use the preprocessor #ifndef.
I'm doing a project that has:
a.h , a.c

b.h, b.c

I include b.h and a.h in main.c

So if I need to include,for example, windows.h and string.h, do I need to do it in both a.h and b.h?(in case both of their source files need to use functions from those headers)
Would it make it slower if I include the same multiple headers file in both files (in case I have multiple headers and not only those two)?
Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a header file contains declarations (naming of thingies) and a source file (.c) contains definitions (the actual thing)

whenever you use a thing (variable, function) that is defined elsewhere, you have to declare it once.

The same is with type definitions/declarations.

So for your question: if you use a type (from b.h) in your header file (a.h), you have to #include the corresponding header file b.h inside the headerfile a.h. if you use a function in your source file d.c, that is declared inside x.h (and defined somewhere in a source file x.c), you have to include x.h inside d.c.

now for the #ifndef inside headerfile: these are guards. remember: I said "once". So you have to guard the header files from reading in multiple times. This is done by

```
#ifndef __A_H_INCLUDED__
#define __A_H_INCLUDED__
//here your stuff comes
#endif
```

so you can multiple times include a.h in your build-tree

so as a rule of thumb: if you need inside a file (header or source) a declared thing, it would be wise to include the corresponding headerfile on the top of this file.

EDIT: you do not have to put declarations inside a header file, if those declarations are only used inside one source file (like static functions or local types and variables).

EDITH:

```
windows.h
  typedef WINWORD long;
  void windowFunction(WINWORD w);

myheader_a.h
  #include <windows.h> // WINWORD
  void mySillyWinFunction(WINWORD w); 

mysource_a.c
  #include <myheader_a.h>
  void mySillyWinFunction(WINWORD w) {
    windowFunction(w);
  }

mysource_b.c
  #include <myheader_a.h>
  /* call */
  mySillyWinFunction(w);
```

Comment: yes, you can put definitions of things inside header files, but this is rarely best practise.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now the difference! For my example, do I need to include other headers file (stdlib.h windows.h string.h etc) in every source file(a.c and b.c for example) that implements function that are declared in their header files?

Comment: if you want to use WinLoadWindow() from windows.h inside a.c and b.c you have to include windows.h in both source files.

Comment: you do not implement a function from stdlib.h or others, they are already implemented (most of the times in the corresponding library)

Comment: I meant to use functions from those libraries in both a.c and b.c...
Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: *"do I need to include other headers file (stdlib.h windows.h string.h etc) in every source file (a.c and b.c for example) that* implements *function that are declared in their header files?"*  user36, it's not just in the source files that **implement** the functions, you want to include the header files with declarations of functions that you want to **call**.  this was particularly necessary in old implementations of C so that the calling function knows what species of animals are being passed to and from the function being called.